# Gmail picking up message body as an attachment

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a very simple email script, as shown below. When I send an email to myself, it works in all clients except Gmail, where the message body is empty, and a HTML file attachment appears which contains the content!

```
$headers = "From: Me <me@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html, charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = <<<EOM
<p>Hello Me,</p>
<p>This is a test message.</p>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p><strong>You</strong><br>example.com</p>\r\n
EOM;

mail("you@example.com\r\n", "Test Message\r\n", $message, $headers);
```

Any insight in to the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `\r\n` in `mail("you@example.com\r\n", "Test Message\r\n", $message, $headers);` and in the message heredoc.

Comment: Same issue unfortunately.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change your headers to the following:

```
$headers = "From: Me <me@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

or

```
$headers = "From: Me <me@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Your headers were not properly formatted.

Consult the manual on PHP.net

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Neither changing the charset, nor concatenating the `\r\n` to the end of the string makes a difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mpdc Using your code gave me an attachment, as opposed to this, which worked. Tested with my Gmail.

Comment: @mpdc There is a problem with the `From:` though. Give me a minute, I will check something.

Comment: @mpdc I forgot to add a dot to the header `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";`, it may have had an impact on it. I've made a slight edit.

Comment: Found it! Copying your code exactly lead me to find the comma which should have been a semi-colon in the line `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html, charset=UTF-8\r\n";` between the parameters... thanks!

Comment: @mpdc That's great, glad to hear it, *cheers* happy to have been of help.